# find all possible path in graph using function in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph-theory

I am creating a graph, and in that graph I want to find all possible paths. For example, in that graph, if I want to go from 1 to 3, it will take two ways. 1->2->3 or 1->4->3, so I have created a generated function for finding all possible paths. Is there any good approach for finding all possible paths for a graph? code is given below

```
let graph = {
    1: [2, 4],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [1, 4]
  };
function findAllPath(graph, start, end) {
    let queue = [];
    queue.push([start]);
    let paths = [];
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        let curPath = queue.shift();
        let lastNode = curPath[curPath.length - 1];
        if (lastNode === end) {
            paths.push(curPath);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < graph[lastNode].length; i++) {
                let nextNode = graph[lastNode][i];
                let newPath = [...curPath, nextNode];
                queue.push(newPath);
            }
        }
    }
    return paths;
}
console.log(findAllPath(graph,1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

```
Set cost of every link to 1
Apply Dijkstra to find cheapest path
Increment cost of links in path
Repeat until no new path found
```

Implementation in C++:

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/2fdae739a4a4dad3b6ad4c510719078edd3e228b/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L120-L168

Small test run:

[image]

The complete PathFinder documentation for the finding all paths option:

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths